# How to get addEventListener to work with a select tag

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<select id="country" >
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="india">India</option>
 <option value="australia">Australia</option>
 <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var a = document.getElementById('country');
b.addEventListener('select',function () {alert(this.value);} ,false);
```

I want to show the selected value in an alert box when the user selects an option from the list.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Use [**`change`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event as `select` event is invoked when some text is selected in an element.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('country');
a.addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="country">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Please select your country</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `<select onchange="alert(this.value)"` would work too.

Comment: If event listener is not working, try this: `a.addEventListener('change', event => alert(event.target.value));`